# Why does my request return an empty list？

Tags: python, web-crawler

When I use XPath to crawl and parse the content of Tencent commonweal, all the returned lists are empty.
The following below is my code(The information of headers is hidden).And the target url is https://gongyi.qq.com/succor/project_list.htm#s_tid=75.I would appreciate it if someone could help me solve this problem.

```
import requests
import os
from lxml import etree

if __name__ =='__main__':

    url = 'https://gongyi.qq.com/succor/project_list.htm#s_tid=75'
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': XXX    }
    response = requests.get(url=url,headers=headers)
    page_text = response.text
    tree = etree.HTML(page_text)
    li_list = tree.xpath('//div[@class="pro_main"]//li')
    for li in li_list:
        title = li.xpath('./div[2]/div/a/text()')[0]
        print(title)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what is actually happening here is that you can only access the first `ul` inside the `pro_main` div, because all those `li` items and their parent are populated by **JavaScript**, thus your list won't be there by the time you scrape the html with `requests.get()`, it will be empty!

The good news is that the JS script in questions populates the data using an API and just exactly how the website does it, you may as well retrieve those titles using the actual **API** and print them.

```
import requests, json
import os

if __name__ =='__main__':

    url = 'https://ssl.gongyi.qq.com/cgi-bin/WXSearchCGI?ptype=stat&s_status=1&s_tid=75'
    resp = requests.get(url).text
    resp = resp[1:-1] #Result is wrapped in (), so we get rid of those
    jj = json.loads(resp)
    
    for i in jj["plist"]:
        title = i["title"]
        print(title)
```

You can explore the API by printing `jj` to see if there's more info that you may need later!

Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help！ You helped me solve this problem.In addition，if it's convenient for you to tell me the meaning of resp[1,-1].

Comment: I am glad I could help! Of course, I have put a little comment next to the part, but basically what we are doing there is **string slicing**. The response we get from the API is rather abnormal, as it is not a normal JSON string. It is wrapped up in a pair of "( )", so we need to get the rid of those in order to call json.loads() later on. resp[1,-1] means "give the resp from the second to the last (not included) character".

Comment: I accepted your answer a few weeks ago.But I  still have some doubts.Where did you find the returned JSON data?

Comment: If you take a look at the requests made from the page's js (In firefox, it's the **Network** tab of the Web Developer Tools), you will see that at some point a `GET` request is made to this enpoint: `https://ssl.gongyi.qq.com/cgi-bin/WXSearchCGI?ptype=stat&s_status=1,1&jsoncallback=_CallbackSearch&s_tid=75.I&s_puin=&s_fid=&s_key=&p=&_=1617008778770`, we already knew that the data you were looking to scrape was being fetched asynchronously as you couldn't get it at first, and this one we've found just really looks like the API the page is using to download the data

Comment: Turns out it is, as if we try to perform the get request onto it, it returns exactly what you want. The request is performed with Python `request` module, throught the `request.get()` method, as we are to perform a GET request. This will return a response object, of which we'd like to access its text contents (so we use the `text` attribute).